# Is "Risque potentiel" a pleonasm?

Tags: adjectifs, noms

I wonder if saying "il y a un **risque potentiel** à utiliser cette solution" is a pleonasm. As a matter of fact, isn't the very notion of risk describing something that could potentially happen?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Risque potentiel* est effectivement un pléonasme, mais c'est devenu ces dernières décennies une expression assez courante que l'on peut parfois comprendre comme une version atténuée de *risque*, quand elle sous entend que le risque est lui-même hypothétique.

[image]

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse, le graphique est très parlant. :)

Answer (score 2):

Un risque étant une possibilité, et "potentiel" qualifiant quelque chose de possible, cela revient en effet à dire "une possibilité possible" qui est naturellement un pléonasme.

Comment: à la place on peut dire `il y a un danger potentiel à utiliser cette solution` ;)

Comment: @Cocoduf je nen peux accepter qu'une réponse, mais celle-ci est aussi satisfaisante que celle de jlliagre. Merci beaucoup.

Comment: @Flying_whale c'est très juste, merci beaucoup. ;)